# How can streaming data from Google Analytic to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, streaming, google-analytics-api

I have a website, I would like to stream data from Google Analytic (without Google Analytic 360) to BigQuery, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: how or where are you receiving your Google Analytic data?

Comment: On my website, Guillaume!

Answer (score 1):

There is only such an opportunity for app + web property. If you want to transfer data from a common web property, you need to create an app + web one as well as a project in firebase. Then transfer your data from web propetry to app + web via data streams. Then set up integration between app + web and firebase and between firebase project and bigquery.